# What datatype should i use to store non terminating rational numbers

Tags: java, numbers, type-conversion

For example, when I store 5/3 as a double, I get 1.0 returned. What datatype should I use for real numbers like 5/3 so that it returns 1.67 in java?

Comment: The problem is how you perform the calculation, not how you store the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `5.0/3` and you will get 1.666....6667.

`5/3` is integer, truncated to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like ((double) 5) / 3. This will tell the compiler to cast the values to double.

As for what representation one should use with fractions : Either choose a sufficient precision with a double, or create your own fractional type.